# WCF Service Type not found

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting the following error:

```
The type 'Drive_Service.DriveSessionsController', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

I understand that this can be thrown if the service names and namespace aren't the same but I have checked it over probably 50 times, and it looks the same to me. I am unsure why I am getting this error.

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<services>
  <service name="Drive_Service.DriveSessionsController">
    <endpoint address="DriveSessionsController" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Drive_Service.ISessionController"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55534"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="Drive_Service.ServiceWithCallback">
    <endpoint address="ServiceWithCallback" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Drive_Service.IServiceWithCallback"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55534"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

SVC Markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Drive_Service.DriveSessionsController" CodeBehind="DriveSessionsController.svc.cs" %>
```

SVC Code

```
namespace Drive_Service
{
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class DriveSessionsController : ISessionController
{
    #region Fields
    private Object syncRoot = new Object();
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    #endregion


    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the flag indicating to use the .NET 2 runtime in conjunction
    /// with the assembly .NET runtime.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully { get; private set; }
    #endregion


    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public DriveSessionsController()
    {
        ICLRRuntimeInfo clrRuntimeInfo = (ICLRRuntimeInfo)RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeInterfaceAsObject(Guid.Empty, typeof(ICLRRuntimeInfo).GUID);

        try
        {
            clrRuntimeInfo.BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
            LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = true;
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = false;
        }

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.ProcessUpdate);
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }
    #endregion


    #region Internal Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Interface to the common language runtime information.
    /// </summary>
    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("BD39D1D2-BA2F-486A-89B0-B4B0CB466891")]
    private interface ICLRRuntimeInfo
    {
        void xGetVersionString();
        void xGetRuntimeDirectory();
        void xIsLoaded();
        void xIsLoadable();
        void xLoadErrorString();
        void xLoadLibrary();
        void xGetProcAddress();
        void xGetInterface();
        void xSetDefaultStartupFlags();
        void xGetDefaultStartupFlags();

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnect the client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sessionID">The session id.</param>
    private void ClientDisconnect(string sessionID)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (SessionManager.IsClientConnected(sessionID))
            {
                SessionManager.DeleteClient(sessionID);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate the client data for the service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private ClientData GenerateClientData()
    {
        DataTranslator translator = new DataTranslator();
        SystemData systemData = translator.GetSystemData;
        ClientData data = new ClientData();

        data.UpdatedData = new List<DataValue>();
        data.DriveStatusExchange = DriveStatusExchange.ERROR;

        foreach (DriveStatusExchange status in DriveStatusExchange.GetValues())
        {
            if (status.Value == systemData.Status.ToString())
            {
                data.DriveStatusExchange = status;
                break;
            }
        }

        data.UpdatedData.Add(new DataValue() { Symbol = data.DriveStatusExchange.Value, Value = 0 });

        return data;
    }
    #endregion


    #region External Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Executed when client is subscribed to notifications from server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientGuid"></param>
    public void SubscribeToNotifications(string clientGuid)
    {
        ISessionCallbackContract ch = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISessionCallbackContract>();

        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            SessionManager.BrowserValue = clientGuid;

            if (!SessionManager.IsClientConnected(clientGuid))
            {
                SessionManager.AddCallbackChannel(clientGuid, ch);

                OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closing += new EventHandler(Channel_Closing);
                OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);                    
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executed when client is unsubscribed to notifications from server.
    /// </summary>
    public void UnsubscribeToNotifications()
    {
        ClientDisconnect(OperationContext.Current.Channel.SessionId);
    }
    #endregion


    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Process updating for each client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ProcessUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientData data = GenerateClientData();

        if (SessionManager.GetCallbackChannels().Count() > 0)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                IEnumerable<ISessionCallbackContract> allChannels = SessionManager.GetCallbackChannels();
                allChannels.ToList().ForEach(c => c.SendNotificationToClients(data));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle closing the channel.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Channel_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IContextChannel channel = (IContextChannel)sender;
        ClientDisconnect(channel.SessionId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle a faulted channel.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IContextChannel channel = (IContextChannel)sender;
        ClientDisconnect(channel.SessionId);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Does anybody see something I'm missing?

Cheers.

Comment: Where is the file `DriveSessionsController.svc.cs` located? What is the type of your project (Web Site, Web Application, etc.)?

Comment: It is a WCF Service Library... DLL only that my other projects in the solution can add as a service reference. The .cs file is located in the solution... it does not go to the bin folder... just the DLL which holds all the classes inside of it.

Comment: The DLL has to go into the /bin folder, otherwise the types from it will not be loaded.

Comment: It is in the bin folder.

Comment: Decomiling the DLL displays the .cs code in it.